# Google Adsense Management API: servingLimitExceeded with a few queries

Tags: adsense-api

We are receiving a servingLmitExceeded after making a few queries to the Adsense Management API for obtaining daily info about each app. We are connecting to 5 accounts.

What we do is first obtain a list of the apps of each account running a report of the last 30d:

```
$start_date = 'today-30d';
$end_date = 'today-1d';

$options = array(
    'metric' => array('EARNINGS'),
    'dimension' => array('APP_ID','APP_NAME'),
);
```

Then, for each app (like 36 in total divided in all the accounts) we run the following report:

```
$start_date = $today->format("Y-m-d");
$end_date = $today->format("Y-m-d");

$options = array(
    'metric' => array('EARNINGS','AD_REQUESTS','AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE','AD_REQUESTS_CTR','AD_REQUESTS_RPM','CLICKS','COST_PER_CLICK'),
    'dimension' => array('APP_ID','COUNTRY_CODE'),
    'filter' => array('APP_ID=@'.$app),
    'sort' => '+APP_ID'
);
```

After a few apps, we receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            { 
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "servingLimitExceeded",
                "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Serving Limit Exceeded"
    }
}
```

We think that we aren't hiting any of the limits that appear here: https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/appendix/limits

We are doing less than 50 requests in total per day and our limits now are 100 queries per 100 second per user:

[image]

If we check the Google APIs console, it appears that the errors are being thrown by adsense.accounts.list

[image]

Does anybody knows how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A simple retry policy for the API call has worked for us.

It'll often go through if we retry 2-3 times with a 30s wait.

Comment: Hi freddygv, thanks for your answer. We have also stablished a retry policy and is working. The thing is ... it shouldn't happen. We sometimes get the servingLimitExceeded in the first request of the day :-s